# ScrollView in custom dailog is filling the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

[image: This is my dialog, am missing the two buttons]Am having an issue how to appropriate set my scorll view for my two TextView **Peaks** and **Peak_index**. Basically they are filling all my custom dailog and not showing the delete button and cancel button. I want the scrollView for both my results at **Peaks** and **Peak_index**, but the scrollView is effecting on the two button and not showing on the dialog. What should I do in this case? Also the peaks are taking so much space from the dialog. why is that?. http://postimg.org/image/pk3qluwut/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:text="Peaks in KPa"
        android:textColor="#040307" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:text="time in sec."
        android:textColor="#040307" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="Peaks"
            android:textColor="#040307" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_Index"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="@string/Peaks_index"
            android:textColor="#040307" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:padding="3dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Del"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"

            android:text="Delete File" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i do not seem to get you sir, can you please explain to me again sorry, also i do not think your xml is complete, where is the closing tags for the scrollview?

Comment: Check the picture of my dialog. The two buttons Delete and cancel are not showing in my custom layout. I'm wondering why. The problem showed when I put the ScrollView to let my values at both TextView to scroll, because they are many.

Comment: and sorry for ads things inside

Comment: please sir is this exactly how your xml is or it is editted? if it is, can you please post the whole xml, i think it is not correct your xml, correct me if im wrong

Comment: Peak_Num and  text_Index are all my values showing here. I set ScrollView so I can see at the final scroll my two buttons. But my implementation is wrong.

Comment: How do you add your data? Plz show us your code.

Comment: it is long story. Am reading from sensors and trying to find the peaks and peaks index. so it depends on me! I might press on the sensor and have only two values to show up at these two TextView **Peak_num** and **text_index**. If i press and create many peaks, they should show up in scroll view, because the view screen of the dialog is not enough for all the data.

Comment: Wrap content on Scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

This is because scrollview height is match parent, it should be wrap_content or 0 or fixed value.